# Why is apt-get install libsqlite3-dev giving me a 404 error?

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite, apt-get, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to install a sqlite3 gem using bundler and am getting the common `Failed to build native gem extensions` error. I'm trying to install the necessary files to fix this and successfully installed ruby-dev using `apt-get install`, but when I run `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` I get this error:

```
Err http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com jaunty-updates/main libsqlite3-dev 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2
404 Not Found [IP: 174.129.253.100 80]
Err http://ec2-us-east-mirror1.rightscale.com jaunty-updates/main libsqlite3-dev 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2
404 Not Found
Err http://ec2-us-east-mirror2.rightscale.com jaunty-updates/main libsqlite3-dev 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2
404 Not Found
Err http://ec2-us-east-mirror3.rightscale.com jaunty-updates/main libsqlite3-dev 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2
404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ec2-us-east-mirror3.rightscale.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-dev_3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2_i386.deb      404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried running apt-get update and again got a bunch of `404 not found` errors, and running the command with `--fix-missing` didn't do anything.

Any idea on what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out I'm using an old version Ubuntu (9.04) and, since I don't want to upgrade, I needed to point to old repositories. The issue is addressed in this question on superuser.com : https://superuser.com/questions/339537/where-can-i-get-theold-repositories-for-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty